# Create light weight (trimmed-down) Windows live CD

Tags: windows-live

I need to create a Windows live CD. Is there any way I can create a light weight Windows (any version) live CD through which I can just get the basic windows explorer. The purpose is  just to copy important files from/to a crashed system quickly. I encounter scenarios like this often and it usually takes a lot of time booting live Linux CDs. Any ideas would be very helpful.

Comment: I don't think any "live windows cd" will boot faster than any live linux cd!

Comment: precisely that's why I want it trimmed down

Answer (score 4, accepted):

BartPE is what you are looking for.

http://www.nu2.nu/pebuilder/

Although there is no explorer support, there is a file manager for it as well as the command prompt. Plus, countless plugins and driver support.

Comment: I think booting a live linux cd takes less time than booting a Bart PE cd.

Comment: One added benefit of BartPE is that antivirus software can be run on the drive.

Comment: It might be nice to get an updated version now Windows 7 is available. Using the Windows AIK you can built a Pre-boot Environment CD or USB out of any version

Comment: Can it access network resources?

Comment: Yes it can aslong as you inject the appropriate drivers. We used to use bartpe all the time to image machines in mass.

Comment: How to get windows explorer in Bart PE? i typed explorer in run and it threw an error.

Comment: Look for A43 File Management Utility.

Answer (score 0):

I'd be inclined to produce an optimised Windows image using [nLite](http://www.nliteos.com/nlite.html) as the base for BartPE to work it's magic.

Comment: -1 advocating violations of EULA

Comment: Which bit states that?

Comment: The one about modifications.